# Dynamically add rowspan with table created from array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I have table that is dynamically created from an array. Using PHP, how can I dynamically add rowspan when the data is repeated? I would like 'Youth Classes' to be displayed only once and have a rowspan=2.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Type] => Youth Classes
            [Class] => Preschool Class
            [Day] => Saturday
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Type] => Youth Classes
            [Class] => Grade School
            [Day] => Friday
        )
)

<?php
/*Load csv file into array*/
$file = 'list.csv';
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
$headers = array_shift($rows);
$csv = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $csv[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
}

/*Build Table*/
echo "\t\t<table class='table'>\n";
echo "\t\t\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
        echo "\t\t\t\t<th>";
        echo $header;
        echo "</th>\n";
    }
    echo "\t\t\t</tr>\n";
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    echo "\t\t\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
        echo "\t\t\t\t<td>";
        echo $cell;
        echo "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t\t\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "\t\t</table>\n";
?>
```

Comment: This should works for only two rows, or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each row, you could check if the "above-cell" is the same, and cancel to write if it is. And, you could count the number of "below-cells" are the same to compute the number of `rowspan` you have to write.

The code below works if two or more rows are the same.

```
/*Build Table*/
echo "\t\t<table class='table'>\n";

// Your header code skipped here...

foreach ($csv as $rid => $row) { // Add key $rid here
    echo "\t\t\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $cid => $cell) { // Add key $cid here

        // If above cell is the same, skip.
        if ($rid > 0 && isset($csv[$rid-1]) && $csv[$rid-1][$cid] == $cell) 
            continue;

        // Check amount of "below cells" that are the same :
        $rspan = 1 ; $idx = 1 ;
        while (isset($csv[$rid + $idx]) && $csv[$rid + $idx][$cid] == $cell) {
            $rspan++;
            $idx++;
        }

        // Write rowspan if needed.
        echo "\t\t\t\t<td".($rspan > 1 ? ' rowspan="' . $rspan . '"' : '') . ">";
        echo $cell;
        echo "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t\t\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "\t\t</table>\n";
```

Outputs :

```
    <table class='table'>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Youth Classes</td>
            <td>Preschool Class</td>
            <td>Saturday</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Grade School</td>
            <td>Friday</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would group your csv data into a multi-dimensional array then count the number of rows in each category.  This will dictate the value to feed `rowspan` and if `rowspan` even needs to be written at all.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TVaFS))

```
$csv=<<<CSV
Youth Classes,Grade School,Monday
Adult Classes,Grade School,Tuesdayday
Youth Classes,Grade School,Friday
Youth Classes,Preschool Class,Saturday
CSV;

foreach (explode("\n", $csv) as $line) {
    $row = str_getcsv($line, ",");
    $grouped[array_shift($row)][] = $row;
}
//var_export($grouped);

echo "<table>\n";
foreach ($grouped as $category => $group) {
    $rows=sizeof($group);
    foreach ($group as $i => $row) {
        echo "\t<tr>\n";
            if(!$i){  // if this is the first row of the subarray (in other words: [0])
                echo "\t\t<th" , ($rows>1 ? " rowspan=\"$rows\"" : "") , ">$category</th>\n";
            }
            echo "\t\t<td>" , implode("</td>\n\t\t<td>", $row) , "</td>\n";
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Source Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Youth Classes</th>
        <td>Grade School</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Grade School</td>
        <td>Friday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Preschool Class</td>
        <td>Saturday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Adult Classes</th>
        <td>Grade School</td>
        <td>Tuesdayday</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Rendered Output: (courtesy of phptester.com)

[image]